# How to add suffixes to an amount of money in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a game where you earn money, and it is very easy to get rich. I want to make it so that if you get money more than a million, instead of showing 1234567, it shows 1.2 million. The process I am trying to go for if the number is more than a million is:

1: get the first two digits

2: remove the first two digits

3: store the remaining digits into a list

4: divide the length of the list by 3

5: get that value in the list of suffixes - 1 (because lists start at 0, not 1)

I can make the list of suffixes, I just need help on how to make this process.

Comment: Could you post you code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good starting place for you. Let me know if it helps.

```js
const $ = s => [...document.querySelectorAll(s)];

function formatNumber(n) {
  if (n > 10**9 - 1) {
    return (n / 10**9).toFixed(2) + "b"
  } else if (n > 10**6 - 1) {
    return (n / 10**6).toFixed(2) + "m"
  } else {
    return n
  }
}


$("button")[0]
.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const userInput = $("input")[0].value;
  const formattedNumber = formatNumber(userInput);
  $("#display")[0].innerText = formattedNumber;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<input type="number">
<button>Go</button>

<div id="display">output</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient approach that doesn't require any parsing - just simple string manipulation:

- Get the digits greater before the 6 digit mark by subtracting the length of the string by 6
- For the digit immediately after the 6 digit mark, you can use `charAt` and get the character at the index of the length of the string minus 6

Result:

```js
const num = "13356789";

function wordify(number) {
  if (number.length > 6) {
    const start = num.substring(0, number.length - 6);
    const second = num.charAt(number.length - 6);
    return `${start}.${second} million`;
  }
}

console.log(wordify(num));
```

Try it yourself with custom numbers:

```js
function wordify(number) {
  if (number.length > 6) {
    const start = number.substring(0, number.length - 6);
    const second = number.charAt(number.length - 6);
    return `${start}.${second} million`;
  }else{
    return `number must have at least 6 digits`;
  }
}

num.addEventListener('input', () => {
  result.innerHTML = wordify(num.value);
});
```

```html
Enter a number: <input id="num" type="number"><br/><br/> Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling all cases (thousands, millions and billions):

```js
let money = 1234567;
let strMoney = String(money);

if(strMoney.length >= 7 && strMoney.length <= 9) {
  console.log(Math.round(money/ 1000000 * 100)/100, 'million')
}else if(strMoney.length > 9) {
  console.log(Math.round(money/ 1000000000 * 100)/100, 'billion')
}else if(strMoney.length <= 6 && strMoney.length >= 4){
  console.log(Math.round(money/ 1000 * 100)/100, 'thousand')
}else {
  console.log(money)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Cash Suffixes Function JavaScript**

---

> Wiki: [Cash Suffixes](https://ageofindustry.fandom.com/wiki/Cash_Suffixes)
> Github Repo: [Cash Suffixes](https://github.com/wuw-sh/cashSuffixes-TypeScript)

```js
function cashSuffixes(value, decimalLength = 2) {
    try {
        if (decimalLength <= 0) decimalLength = 1
        const selectType = Math.log10(Math.abs(value)) / 3 | 0;
        if (selectType === 0) return value;
        const types = ['', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'qd', 'Qn', 'sx', 'Sp', 'O', 'N'];
        let scaled = (value / Math.pow(10, selectType * 3)).toString(), number;
        const split = scaled.split('.'), int = split[0], decimal = split[1];
        if (decimal === undefined) number = int;
        else number = int + '.' + decimal.slice(0, decimalLength);
        return number + types[selectType];
    } catch (e) {
        return value;
    }
}

function numberWithCommas(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

// Example #1
input1.addEventListener('input', () => {
  full_number1.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(input1.value)
  output1.innerHTML = cashSuffixes(input1.value);
});

//Example #2
input2.addEventListener('input', () => {
  full_number2.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(input2.value)
  output2.innerHTML = cashSuffixes(input2.value, dec_len.value);
});
dec_len.addEventListener('input', () => {
  full_number2.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(input2.value)
  output2.innerHTML = cashSuffixes(input2.value, dec_len.value);
});
```

```html
Example #1
<br>
Input Number: <input id="input1" type="number">
<br>
Full Number: <span id="full_number1"></span>
<br>
Output: <span id="output1"></span>
<br>
<br>
Example #2
<br>
Input Number: <input id="input2" type="number">
<br>
Decimal Length: <input id="dec_len" type="number">
<br>
Full Number: <span id="full_number2"></span>
<br>
Output: <span id="output2"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could now use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) with the [`compact`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#notation) notation like this

```js
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', {notation: 'compact'})

num.addEventListener('input', () => {
  result.innerHTML = formatter.format(num.value);
});
```

```html
Enter a number: <input id="num" type="number"><br/><br/> Result: <span id="result"></span>
```